# Render image without a frame number

Tags: rendering

Stoopid question: Kind of like old 3DS Max, can you render a single frame to disk without any frame numbers?

`C:\blender\render\my_image.png`

I.e. Without renaming it directly (or indirectly via a script) `my_image0001.png` >> `my_image.png` or Render Image and then Image Save As.

I'm aware of the solutions above, but just wondered if there is a setting or option to do it one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file output path, if you write the entire file name **with the extension**, Blender will not add the frame number **unless you render a sequence of frames**.

Also, if you still want frame numbers but with a specific position and zero-padding, you can write the full name with extension, and use `#` characters as placeholders for the frame numbers.

More about it here:
[Output — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/properties/output.html#:%7E:text=File%20Path)